# How to load HTML into a <div> using jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, load

So this is my `buildInputFields.php` file, which contains the markup I want to load into my `#add_input_fields` div located in my `articlePostForm.php` file. Both files are in the *same* directory in my theme file:

**buildInputFields.php**

```
<fieldset id="add_fields">
    <legend>Add Fields</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Preview form" class="add" id="preview" />
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
```

**articlePostForm.php**

```
<body>
    <div id="form-container">
        <form>

            ...

            <section>
                <legend>citations</legend>
                <div id="add_input_fields" href="<?=get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/buildInputFields.php" onload="loadInputFields();"></div>
            </section>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is my jQuery:

**loadInputFields.js**

```
function loadInputFields() {
    var href = $('#add_input_fields').attr('href');
    $('#add_input_fields').load(href);

    return false;  //to prevent default action
}
```

I have enqueued and registered .js files as so in my functions.php file in WP. All .js files are located in the theme file's js folder:

**functions.php**

```
function loadInputFields_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/loadInputFields.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadInputFields_js');
```

And I have included it in my header.php file in WP:

**header.php**

```
<head>

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/loadInputFields.js"></script>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="container">
    //end of header.php
```

Basically what I'm doing is creating a form for people to post their own articles on my site. *This is just one part of the form*. In this part of the form, I'm attempting to load in markup that will be accompanied by other jQuery code that features a "plus sign" and "minus sign" to add and remove input fields for people who want to add in cited sources.

The `#add_input_fields` div is where I want to load my markup in from the `buildInputFields.php` file. I want to load it using my jQuery file `loadInputFields.js` which is supposed to select the `#add_input_fields` div, get its href value, set a equal to a local variable, and then load it back into the div using the `.load()` function.

Any advice? I have been trying for two days and all I can do now is huddle up in the corner, pull over my hoodie, and sob endless tears.

NOTE: I understand that a div element cannot use an href attribute. I simply structured the code this way so anyone reading can get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish because I have a terrible way of trying to explain things. You're help is desired and appreciated!

Comment: your question is not clear but you can add data-href for your div.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking - no info on what is happening?  Are you getting any error messages either in the web server logs or the browser console? However, a couple of things strike me: 1. If you have added the js script with wp_enqueue_script then you do not need to add it manually to the header.php as well (assuming you run wp_head() somewhere there).  2. Why are you loading another php script via a page lood event?  Why not just include the other php script with include() in the php directly?